# Can I hard code the Wordpress Static Home Page

Tags: wordpress

We have an issue with a multisite multi-language site that, seemingly at random, the static home page will redirect to another page (again seemingly a random one but always the same). When I go to Settings > Reading  > Static Home Page the entry is blank and won't Save but going to another language, pressing Save and returning to the original language cures the issue (obscure but consistent).

Because this is random behaviour (once, twice a week) on a live site it's very difficult to diagnose a cause. We are not able to reliably reproduce the issue on our staging site.

My question is, is it possible to hardcode the static home page with this;

```
if ($GetURL === ‘example.com/’ ) {
 header('Location: example.com?p=8');
}
```

There are effectively 19 home pages (including translations) so it would have to catch all instances and also read the language cookie.

Are there any issues with this approach?

Does this ring any bells as to cause? (it appears on first sight to be a conflict between Polylanf and Litespeed)